# How to display a key that has multiple values from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a local JSON file:

[image]

and I'm trying to display that data to look like a graph like this:

[image]

I have the graph laid out and I'm trying to display them like props, however I keep getting an error that says props is not defined.

Here is what the code looks like

```
<div>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Athlete</th>
                <th>Muscle-soreness</th>
                <th>Sleep-quality</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        {
                      props.data.map(row => (
                        <tr>
                        <td>{row.athlete}</td>
                        </tr>
                      ))
                    }
            <tr>
                <td>Column1</td>
                <td>Column2</td>
                <td>Column3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
   </div>
```

I'm still pretty new to react so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `this.props.data` instead of only `props.data`?  `props` is a "variable" within the context of your component. So in order to reference it, you must use the `this` keyword :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm getting a new error; TypeError: this.props.data.map is not a function

Comment: How do you get your data?

Comment: What are you passing to the `data` prop? Are you sure it's an array?

Comment: The data is a locally stored file that was made up by somebody else. The values are arrays.

Comment: Can you show us other parts of the app? For example, how do you import your JSON file, how do you pass it from a parent component to this child one?

Comment: By the way, please share your whole JSON file in your question but not as an image, just copy/and paste it. Also, your JSON file looks like an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you don't provide an answer to the comments I think you are still trying to figure it out. As far as I see your JSON data is an object. So somehow you need to map this object and pick the proper values. In the current shape of this data, it is a little bit tricky to do this.

First, we use `Object.values` to get the object values. Since all the key lengths are equal ( this is how all the data sync) we are just mapping the first value of the object. Actually the first or the second or any value does not matter here, we just need to map one value to track an iterator index.

Inside this mapped array we are again using another map to get the values. For each `td` we use our index coming from the upper map.

By the way, I've used indexes as keys but finding a unique key would be better.

```js
const App = ( props ) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const values = Object.values( data );
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Athlete</th>
            <th>Muscle-soreness</th>
            <th>Sleep-quality</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {values[ 0 ].map( ( _, i ) => (
            <tr key={i}>{values.map( ( value, key ) => <td key={key}>{value[ i ]}</td> )}</tr>
          ) )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

const data = {
  athlete: [ "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" ],
  "muscle-soreness": [ 5, 6, 7 ],
  "sleep-quality": [ 5, 6, 7 ],
};

ReactDOM.render( <App data={data} />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```